# Function that reset the 8th bit of the string?

Tags: c

I am trying make a code that resets the 8th bit of the string. I have made it work, but I believe it is not still correct. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void make7bit(unsigned char *s, unsigned int n)
{

int i = 0;
int x =0;

while(x <n)
{
    if(*s |= (1 << 7))  //it still works, whatever I have 1 << 7 or 1 << 3
        *s = '0';

    i++;
    x++;

}

printf("%s", s);

return NULL;

}


int main()
{
    char A[] ={"11111111"};
    int n = 8;

    make7bit(A, n);


    return 0;
}
```

I dont understand the line `if(*s |= (1 << 7))`, because whatever it is 1 << 7 or something else (for example 1 << 3) it still works, or at least it reset the last bit of the string. I am quite sure I am doing something wrong here, but what? I think the code is now resetting the last bit of the string and not the 8th one as I would like...

Could someone help me with this one?

Comment: looks like you don't know what you're doing, so I have to ask, what do you mean by *8th* bit and *reset*? what's the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

`1 << 3` is `00001000`, `1 << 7` is `10000000`.. You're not clearing the 8th bit in any case.

If you want to clear a bit (not setting it), you should:

```
*s &= ~(1 << 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. What does it means '8th bit of the string'? You should reset 8th bit of every byte? Or something else? Why do you set *s to '0'? Should results for "11111111" and "12345678" be the same? Do you assume usual string, or maybe every char represents one bit?

If you wish to reset 8th bit of every byte, you should use

```
*s &= 0x7F;
```

But generally your source contains no any line which corresponts to task described.

Btw, your loop is senseless. You described two loop variables, but never use it; you just patches one byte 8 times in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Your are done the left shift with the value one.

```
 1 << 7 
 Now the bit is 10000000.
```

So you are doing the or operation with this value. Here *s value is,

```
 *s=1. Bit position of one is. 00110001.
```

Because ascii value of 1 is 49.Here you are using the character so the value is taken in ascii. And bit representation for one byte.Now or operation.

```
 00110001
 10000000
 ---------
 10110001
```

So the value is non zero so the if condition works and the position is changed into 0.